# What about WSO2 ESB Analytics and Zipkin integration?

Tags: wso2, zipkin, opentracing, wso2-esb

I am thinking of integrating WSO2 ESB and Zipkin following Open Tracing using a [Customize Statics Publisher implemented](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Customizing+Statistics+Publishing) by me.

The idea is enable statics and trace in WSO2 ESB.

Is there any other approach to to achieve this? Is this approach correct?